How to apply @Validated on a List request body?
Given:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class VocabularyRequest {
  @Null(groups = CollectionCreation.class)
  @NotNull(groups = VocabularyCreation.class)
  private Long collectionId;

  @Valid private List<MeaningVariantRequest> meaningVariants;
}

This @Validated works:
  @PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  @Override
  public Mono<VocabularyResponse> create(
      @Validated(VocabularyCreation.class) @RequestBody VocabularyRequest request) {
    return super.create(request);
  }

But this (applied on a List) not:
  @PostMapping(value = "/bulk", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  @Validated(VocabularyCreation.class)
  public Flux<VocabularyResponse> createBatch(
      @RequestBody List<@Valid VocabularyRequest> requests) {
    return service(VocabularyService.class).createBatch(requests);
  }

Change to this, still not work:
  @PostMapping(value = "/bulk", consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public Flux<VocabularyResponse> createBatch(
      @Validated(VocabularyCreation.class) @RequestBody List<VocabularyRequest> requests) {
    return service(VocabularyService.class).createBatch(requests);
  }

If changing to @RequestBody List<@Validated(VocabularyCreation.class) VocabularyRequest> requests, got compile error:
'@Validated' not applicable to type use

As the title, any solution? Thanks for help!!

Have you tried @Validated(VocabularyCreation.class) List<@Valid VocabularyRequest> requests?

let me try and see

Not working man

What if you annotate the entire method with @Validated(...)? In theory, this should apply the validation group to all the params to validate

Tried (I mentioned alréady), but no luck man

You need to create VocabularyBulkRequest which contains list of VocabularyRequest.
It will change your API, but having list on top level is bad practice anyway.

That is the only way, right? I was thinking about it. Somehow it's not "legal" way

'It will change your API, but having list on top level is bad practice anyway' - where did you get this idea? In my book, having extra wrappers for no reason is bad practice

@crizzis Itis easier to extend. If you need you can always add extra attributes.

@talex if being able to extend a list response by adding extra fields would be a such a great idea, you would use it locally also. Do you wrap all the lists returned from all the methods in your code in extra wrappers, so that one day you might want to return an extra value? The need to do that is nothing else but a code smell to me.

@crizzis if i want to have backward compatible API I'll have such wrappers in Java code too.
